# Does \n\r behave differently on different OS?

Tags: operating-system, terminal, telnet, eol

I have a server and a client program that talks to eachother over a socket connection. 
It sends strings of data that I monitor via telnet / (or terminal? on mac).

It works fine, when I use my MAC as a server and my PC as a client.
It does **not** work when I use my MAC as a client, and PC as a server... (!?)

Could it be that it the interperets  `"\n\r"` (EOL?) differently since there are two different OS?

Does anybody have a clue / tip / workaround on how to solve this easy?

Comment: On Windows, EOL is actually "\r\n", not "\n\r".  Try changing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows actually uses `\r\n` as EOL. It shouldn't behave differently on different OSes, though. Mac uses `\r`, so it ignores `\n`, and vice versa for *nix. Windows ignores both `\r` and `\n` unless they're next to each other in the order `\r\n`.

When programming with EOL, most languages only use `\n` and auto-convert the format when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Macs use CR ("\r") as their single end-of-line character. Since Windows uses "\r\n" (CR-LF) for end-of-line, you may need to compensate for that in your code.